# Monogame - custom json content importer

Tags: c#, monogame, tilemap, json

I am trying to build a JSON tile map importer for the content pipeline of Monogame but I'm having difficulty doing so. I have been following [this](http://dylanwilson.net/creating-custom-content-importers-for-the-monogame-pipeline) tutorial and got something... But now it appears my entire JSON level cannot be loaded since it has an array-based structure, and my code expects an object, here is my level file:

```
[
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2],
    [2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,2,2],
    [2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,2,2],
    [2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2],
    [2,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    [2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
]
```

And below are the custom content pipeline classes I made:

```
public class MapFile
{
    private MapFile map;

    public MapFile(MapFile map)
    {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public int[,] MapContent { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
[ContentImporter(".json", DefaultProcessor = "TileMapProcessor",
DisplayName = "TileMap Importer")]
public class MapImporter : ContentImporter<MapFile>
{
    public override MapFile Import(string filename, ContentImporterContext context)
    {
        context.Logger.LogMessage("Importing Map file: {0}", filename);

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            return (MapFile)serializer.Deserialize(streamReader, typeof(MapFile));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MapReader : ContentTypeReader<MapFile>
{
    protected override MapFile Read(ContentReader input, MapFile existingInstance)
    {
        string json = input.ReadString();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(json);
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        MapFile mapFile = (MapFile)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(MapFile));
        MapFile map = input.ContentManager.Load<MapFile>(mapFile.MapContent.ToString());
        return new MapFile(map);
    }
}
```

**The problem:**
As I said above, I get the following error at the content pipeline app:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current > JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'my class' because the type requires a > JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.            >{"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type >that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List > that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be > added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Changing the type from `int[,]` to `List<List<int>>` would be easy, but I have the following code to generate visual representation of the map files:

```
public void Generate(MapFile map, int size)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < map.MapContent.GetLength(1); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < map.MapContent.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            int number = map.MapContent[y, x];
            if (number > 0)
            {
                CollisionTiles.Add(new CollisionTiles(number, new Rectangle(x * size, y * size, size, size)));
            }
            Width = (x + 1) * size;
            Height = (y + 1) * size;
        }
    }
}
```

So that is what I am using. I hope you can help me, I've got everything right, including the collision so loading my maps from XNB files is the last thing I need to do. Thanks in advance!
**Edit:** new level format:

```
{
    "Name": "My Level",
    "MapContent": 
    [
      1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
      2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,
      2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,2,2,
      2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,2,2,
      2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,
      2,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
      2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
      2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
      2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your level file needs to look like this:

```
{
    "MapContent": 
    [
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2],
    [2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,2,2],
    [2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,2,2],
    [2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2],
    [2,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    [2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
    ]
}
```

Note that I've changed the outer square brackets (`[`, `]`) to curly braces (`{`, `}`) because you're deserializing into a JSON object.

It may look a little odd that you have to add the `MapContent` property to the file but one advantage of this approach is that you'll be able to easily add extra metadata to your map file. For example, you could add a `Name` property like this:

```
{
    "Name": "My Level",
    "MapContent": 
    [
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
    [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2],
    [2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,2,2],
    [2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,2,2],
    [2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2],
    [2,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    [2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
    ]
}
```

And change your `MapFile` class accordingly

```
public class MapFile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int[,] MapContent { get; set; }
}
```

Btw, while we are on the topic. I find it very strange that you are passing a `MapFile` into the `MapFile` constructor. I think you can remove the constructor completely to simplify the code.

```
public MapFile(MapFile map)
```

If you really don't want to change the level format you might be able to change the deserialization method instead. However, I think this approach is going to lead to some pretty confusing code.

Comment: I got the following error: `We don't support multidimensional arrays!`. It doesn't say anything about Newtonsoft.Json so my guess would be the problem is in the Content pipeline itself? I'll fire an issue on the official repo.